# PHP PDO return wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've searched for this but cant find a way to solve this.

```
    $sql = "select count(*) as rule_count from AdminRules where FunctionName = :fn_name and UserLevel in (select user_type from users where user_id = :usid)";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $parameters = array(':fn_name' => $func_name , ':usid' => $user_id );

    if (!$query->execute($parameters)){
        return False;
    }
     echo '[ PDO DEBUG ]: ' . Helper::debugPDO($sql, $parameters);  exit();
    return  ($query->fetch()->rule_count >= 1)?True:False;
```

result of PDO::DEBUG:

> [ PDO DEBUG ]: select count(*) as rule_count from AdminRules where
>   FunctionName = 'admin_control' and UserLevel in (select user_type from
>   users where user_id = '2')

result of query is 0:

> Array ( [rule_count] => 0 )

however i run the same query in phpmyadmin its (rule_count = 1)
[image: screenshot for result in phpmyadmin]

Comment: The SQL you say runs OK has `UserLevel = ` and the debug is `UserLevel in `, not sure, but can you just check the debug version runs.

Comment: maybe you're connected in a different DB? staging DB perhaps

Comment: Can you try this below the if statement?: print_r($query->rowCount());

Comment: yes i submitted that as answer but cant make it answer, should i delete the question @acd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the user_id is unique so its not, actually i was dumbly watching (phpmyadmin which works on online server) and trying to run my code which is connected to local database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the result of your subquery

```
select user_type 
from users 
where user_id = :usid
```

is not a single row, so you should change `=` to `IN` :

```
  $sql = "select count(*) as rule_count from AdminRules where FunctionName =:fn_name and UserLevel IN (select user_type from users where user_id = :usid)";
```